# How does an Android device wake up

Tags: android, wakelock

There are two ways that an Android device can go into "sleep" mode. One is just letting the screen time out and it shuts off automatically. In this case, it isn't clear whether the CPU is still running apps (unless of course they have a partial wake lock). The other case is when you press the power button and the screen goes off. It isn't clear to me whether that is the same thing as letting the screen just time out.

But what I really want to know is what is really happening. For instance, if I press the power button but a phone call comes in, the device will awake and light up and the phone app starts. Is this just the phone app running with a partial wake lock or do manufacturers use custom hardware features that are meant to recognize the phone ringing and take it out of sleep mode?

The reason why I am interested is because if it's hardware controlled, the question that arises is whether there are other hardware related features that are controlled the same way. For instance, is it possible for the GPS receiver to stay alive but only wakes up the device when a valid location is received?

To save on battery consumption, it would be nice if we could cause the device to wake up when certain hardware features are activated. My impression with the WakeLock feature is that it's just a software feature with some minimal support for the power button.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the phone calls, and GPS etc will broadcast `Intents` that you can listen for with a `BroadcastReceiver`. The device would be awake long enough to broadcast them.

(Technically the Android firmware handles the power levels of the device, and gives wakelocks to certain functionality. This gives the impression that the hardware signals allow your code to run, but actually the hardware signals allow Android to run, which allows your code to run.)

So you would register for those intents and be notified inside your `BroadcastReceiver` subclass. The device will be awake for a short period inside your receiver, long enough for you to take control and create your own `WakeLock`.

So:

1. The device does kind of have that feature you are after - although specifically it is controlled by the Android firmware, not entirely hardware. This means that different firmware releases can do things differently. This is quite obvious when watching the debug log output on a GPS tracking app on different devices - watching how the firmware GPS is being used.
2. You can hook the `Intent` and will have time to implement your own `WakeLock`.

I would check out @Commonsware's WakefulIntentService, and make use of that.

- https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Otherwise he has written some very good info about it in his book.

---

**Example of a `BroadcastReceiver` I use to listen for updates from the `LocationProvider`**

This is sample code adapted from production code - I have removed some parts of it, but leave it here to show that this receiver will run despite not having any special code in it.

```
/**
 * Receives broadcasts from the {@link LocationProvider}s. The providers
 * hold a {@link PowerManager.WakeLock} while this code executes. The
 * {@link MyService} code needs to also hold a WakeLock for code that
 * is executed outside of this BroadcastReceiver.
 */
private BroadcastReceiver locationEventReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // get location info
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            Log.d("mobiRic", "LOCATION RECEIVER CALLBACK");

            // check if this is a new location
            Location location = (Location) extras
                .get(android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
            Log.d("mobiRic", "  - intent = [" + intent + "]");
            Log.d("mobiRic", "  - location = [" + location + "]");
            if (location != null)
            {
                updateCurrentLocation(location, false);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

**Example of how I set up the `BroadcastReceiver` to get the GPS events**

Here are 2 (edited) methods I use to make sure my `Service` gets the location events.

```
/**
 * Starts listening for {@link LocationManager#GPS_PROVIDER} location
 * updates.
 */
void doStartLocationListeningGps()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("MY_INTENT_GPS");
    PendingIntent pendingIntentGps = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
        action.hashCode(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        LOCATION_UPDATE_TIME_GPS, 0, pendingIntentGps);
}


/**
 * Registers the {@link #locationEventReceiver} to receive location events.
 */
void registerLocationReceiver()
{
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    /* CUSTOM INTENTS */
    filter.addAction("MY_INTENT_GPS");
    registerReceiver(locationEventReceiver, filter);
}
```

Comment: In order for you to listen for intents in a BroadcastReceiver, the CPU has to be running, which means that you had to have used partial wake lock, otherwise if the device times out or someone presses the power button, your BroadcastReceiver is useless. It would be nice if the hardware feature (like GPS) could simply turn on the CPU at the moment it has data and then send its intent. I'm not sure but I believe only Wi-Fi and the phone have that built in.

Comment: That is not 100% correct. For LocationProviders, you register to receive the Intent and you will get it even if the device is "asleep".

Comment: That's probably because Android automatically adds the partial wake lock to handle the location provider, in which case the device is not asleep at all. How could it be asleep when it not only needs to receive the location but probably perform software processing on it (such as detecting proximity).

Comment: That is now correct - as I said this is handled by the firmware. The firmware provided the LocationProvider with a wakelock. This is for "a short period", just long enough to hit your own BroadcastReceiver code. In your code, you need to get your own wakelock in order to handle the software processing - have added code to show the receiver I use.

Comment: to add - the first code after my receiver runs (i.e. method updateCurrentLocation()) registers a `WakeLock` that I then use for the processing - my recommendation is to use the WakefulIntentService rather than to roll your own.

Comment: How do you know the firmware is operating with a wake lock that is only for a short period of time? I think you're assuming that. It could be that the firmware keeps the CPU permanently on when the BroadcastReceiver is registered. What proof do you have that it is only on for a short period of time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26081/discussion-between-richard-le-mesurier-and-androiddev)